# Preguntas sobre el patron '7 en 1' de sass

Tags: css, sass, scss

Buen día a todos, estoy practicando scss y trabajando con el patron 7 en 1  para la distribución de archivos, aun soy nuevo en el desarrollo web y tengo algunas dudas sobre esto.

1. Tengo una página principal que tiene entradas de blog y cada ves q se le da click abre una una nueva pagina donde se muestra la entrada. dejo la imagen de como ve .[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

gracias espero sus respuestas

mi duda es si todos los nuevos estilos para esa página deben ir en un solo archivo  dentro de la carpeta pages .ejemplo 'pages/_post.scss' o puedo repartir algunos estilos en las carpeta 'components','layout' si es necesario como por ejemplo los comentarios que se muestran pueden ser un componente, he buscado información pero siempre encuentro lo mismo, espero puedan ayudar a resolver mi duda, gracias.

2. si tengo un header y dentro un logo con  un menu ¿los estilos de ese header deben ir en la carpeta layout?estilos como flexbox para poder alinearlos y el menu seria un componente , cierto? quisiera saber si es así como se debe trabajar, hago por esa pregunta porque segui un curso donde metian un header como componente , y me entro la duda si debria ir en la carpeta 'components' o 'layout'

Comment: Se supondría que pages contendrá cosas de una página que no se repitan en otras. Para tu caso, 'pages/_post.scss' debería contener solo cosas muy específicas de ese post, mientras que el resto seguramente quedaría bien en 'components'.

Comment: Algo similar pasa con el header (depende de si es un header va a aparecer en todas las páginas o solo en una). En 'layout' probablemente se especificaría la forma en que dicho header es acomodado dentro de la página, pero el propio header sería preferible ponerlo en 'components'. Y si, los estilos de flexbos en este caso pertenecen al propio componente.

Comment: entiendo saul , el header si aparece en todas las páginas asi que en este caso seria tambien un componente pero a la vez tambien pondria sus estilos en el layout,no? ya que dentro de el tiene el  menu y el logo que necesitan ser posicionados ,corrígeme si me equivoco